# How to ensure enough spacing between the equation sign and LHS expression

Tags: math-mode

I am trying to type the following math equation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$\mid \alpha'(t) \mid = \left< \alpha'(t), \alpha'(t) \right >_p $

\end{document}
```

My question is regarding the equation sign; there is decent spacing between the '=' and the expression on the right, but it ends up being too close to the expression on the left. Is there a way to ensure enough spacing between '=' and the LHS?

Thanks

Comment: I think you mean that `=` is too close to the _left_ hand side, not the right hand side?

Comment: You're right, I apologise for the confusion. I have edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your use of `\mid` which is an infix relation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

$\lvert\alpha'(t) \rvert = \left< \alpha'(t), \alpha'(t) \right >_p $

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is an infix relation?

Comment: @TJ.Kim something like +  in a use such as `a \mid b` to make "a | b"

Comment: @TJ.Kim Prefix: + a b. Postfix: a b +. Infix: a + b.

Comment: @Au101 thanks for pointing out the distinction